# Why is it saying no database selected?

Tags: php, mysql, database

When trying to post data to the database it gives an error saying no database selected. But the content from the database is displaying on a table and select menu.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","radian");
if(!$con)
{
  exit("Couldn't connect: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

$insert_data = "UPDATE enquiries 
                  SET ResponseDate = '".$current_date."',
                      Response = '".$txtResponse."',
                      Enquiry_No = '".$_SESSION['ses_staff']
                  ."' WHERE Enquiry_No = '".$txtStudentId."'";

$execute = mysql_query($insert_data) or die(mysql_error());

$output= '<h4 style="margin-left:1em;width:15em;color:red;"> Response successful!. </h4>';   

}else{

    $output= '<h4 style="margin-left:1em;width:15em;color:red;"> </h4>';   
}
```

Comment: Well, that's not HTML.

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli` and `mysql`

Comment: `mysql_query($insert_data) or die(mysql_error());` - Wow. You started correctly with `mysqli_` and you used `mysql_`.

Comment: And you have an orphaned `} else {`.

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and it will not work anymore, use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `mysqli` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: Indent your code sensibly and the errors **shout out to you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final code should be identical to:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "radian");
    if (!$con) {
        exit("Couldn't connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

    $insert_data = "UPDATE enquiries SET ResponseDate = '" . $current_date . "', Response = '" . $txtResponse . "',Enquiry_No = '" . $_SESSION['ses_staff'] . "' WHERE Enquiry_No = '" . $txtStudentId . "'";

    $execute = mysqli_query($con, $insert_data) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $output = '<h4 style="margin-left:1em;
    width:15em;
    color:red;"> Response successful!. </h4>';
```

Changes made:

- Remove all instances of `mysql_*` and replace with the correct `mysqli_*` function.
- Remove the orphaned `} else {`.

> **Note:** Officially `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. So no point using them. Use either `mysqli_*` or PDO.